# Can we replace these two Peano axioms with this single axiom?

Tags: peano-axioms

Peano Axioms from [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html):

> 1. Zero is a number.

> 2. If $a$ is a number, the successor of $a$ is a number.

> 3. zero is not the successor of a number.

> 4. Two numbers of which the successors are equal are themselves equal.

> 5. (induction axiom.) If a set $S$ of numbers contains zero and also the successor of every number in $S$, then every number is in $S$.

Q: After defining $1$ to be the successor of $0$, $2$ to be the successor of $1$, etc, can we replace Axioms 3 and 4 with

> Axiom 6. $0$, $1$, $2$, etc. are (pairwise) distinct.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: "etc." is a meta-formulation that we cannot use in a formal mathematical language. This is why formal logic is so cumbersome and proofs are usually not formulated in such a language , although they could be formalized.

Comment: @Peter: But then how does one define $1$, $2$, $3$, "etc."? In this context, [Tao](https://books.google.com/books?id=x7avEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA14) does use "etc." and so did [Peano](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog/page/n23)

Comment: [1] Authors can & will use "ETC" in Discussions , not in Axioms. Hence Axiom 6 is not valid. [2] More-over , that Axiom 6 will allow Natural numbers to be like 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,.... , where we have Pair-wise Distinct Elements.

Comment: @Prem: Tao and Peano use "etc." in their formal definitions not discussions.

Comment: My Point [1] , you say "ETC" is there in Axioms , It might be good to include that Part in your Post. My Point [2] still stands , though !

Comment: No, "etc." is NOT formal , mathemticians , even logicians , usually do not formalize their proofs or claims because the proofs would then become virtually unreadbable.

Answer (score 2):

Working in second-order logic, consider a language with a constant $0$ and a unary function symbol $S$.  Let $\Bbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers in the meta-theory.  Looking at the following axiom systems.

System 1

1. $\neg\exists x \,Sx = 0$
2. $\forall x\forall y \,(Sx=Sy\rightarrow x=y)$
3. $\forall U(0\in U\land (\forall x\, (x\in U\rightarrow Sx\in U)))\rightarrow (\forall x\,x\in U)$, where $U$ quantifies over subsets the universe.

System 2

- $(An,m)$ an axiom *schema*.  For all $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n\ne m$, $S^n 0\ne S^m 0$, where $S^n$ is a term applying $S$ $n$ times (and $S^0 0=0)$.
- $(B)$ an axiom same as axiom 3 above.

Assume System 1.  To establish the axioms of System 2, we just need to prove $(An,m)$ for all $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n\ne m$.  Let $n$ be the least natural number such there exists an $m>n$ such that $S^n 0 = S^m 0$.

- If $n=0$ then $0 = S^m 0$, so $0$ is a succesor - in contradiction to axiom 1.
- Otherwise, $S(S^{n-1} 0) = S^n 0 = S^m 0 = S(S^{m-1} 0)$, so by axiom 2, $S^{n-1} 0 = S^{m-1} 0$ in contradiction to $n$ being minimal.

Notice I didn't even have to use the induction axiom 3 to prove this, just that $\Bbb{N}$ is well-ordered in the meta-theory.

Now assume System 2.  To establish the axioms of System 1, we need to prove axioms 1 and 2.  Let $U=\{S^n 0:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ in the meta-theory.  Since this is second-order logic, $U$ satisfies the assumption of axiom B/axiom 3, so $U$ is the whole universe of the model.

If $0=Sx$ for some $x$ in the universe then there is some $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $x=S^n 0$ and then $0=S^{n+1} 0$ which contradicts the axiom $(A0,(n+1))$.

If $x\ne y$ for some $x,y$ in the universe, there are $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $x=S^n 0, y=S^m 0$ and necessarily $n\ne m$.  But then $s^{n+1} 0\ne S^{m+1} 0$ by axiom $(A(n+1),(m+1))$, so $Sx\ne Sy$.

The above proof shows that System 1 and System 2 are equivalent in the sense of $\models$.  I'm not sure whether they're equivalent in the sense of $\vdash$, as I'm unfamiliar with deductive systems for second-order logic and they're not complete anyway.

Addendum: System 1 ($S1$) is finite while System 2 ($S2$) is an infinite schema.  Any finite subset $S2'\subseteq S2$ has a finite model of a circular buffer.  Since any model of $S1$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{N}$, it follows $S2'\not\models S1$.  Assuming that a deductive system of second-order logic allows a proof to only use finitely many axioms - it follows that $S2\not\vdash S1$.  On the other hand, the proof that $S1\models S2$ does not use the second-order induction axiom, so it's valid in first-order logic.  Since first-order logic has a complete deductive system, $S1\vdash S2$ in first-order logic.  Assuming a deductive system of second-order logic can do everything a deductive system of first-order logic can do then $S1\vdash S2$ is second-order logic.

---

Here's a summary if you don't know formal logic

- Axiom $6$ is actually a set of infinitely many axioms.
- Axioms $1+2+3+4+5$ together have only one model up to isomorphism which is $\Bbb{N}$.
- Axiom set $1+2+5+6$ together has only one model up to isomorphism which is $\Bbb{N}$.
- Each and every axiom in $6$ is provable (with a separate finite proof for each) from axioms $1+2+3+4$ together.
- No finite subset of axioms from $1+2+5+6$ can prove either $3$ or $4$ in a finite proof.

So the system consisting of $1+2+3+4+5$ is stronger than $1+2+5+6$ in terms of what you can prove using finite proofs.  However, they both categorically model the natural numbers.